# How list JSON in JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a list in JSON for create a list and push in HTML ul li. And I need create this list with JQuery and I did but don't working. Now, I don't finish this task.:

```
{
  "Nome": "Notícias",
  "Editorias": [
    {
      "Editoria": "Esporte",
      "Id": "574c58853ecb94fd25aeb8a8",
      "Noticias": [
        {
          "Foto": "3.jpg",
          "Título": "Consumo de chocolate e depressão estão associados.",
          "Texto": "Sint dolor consequat occaecat non aliqua non adipisicing id. Lorem Lorem anim quis incididunt laboris consequat sunt id. Ad laborum magna ad non do dolor.\r\n",
          "Data de publicação": "06-01-2015"
        },
        {
          "Foto": "3.jpg",
          "Título": "Objetos recriados em madeira",
          "Texto": "Nisi deserunt irure deserunt est ut consequat consectetur enim aliqua fugiat ut minim. Minim amet velit aliquip aute id mollit incididunt veniam. Adipisicing elit duis dolore et. Proident occaecat qui ullamco incididunt ea pariatur aliquip veniam sit nisi officia aliquip.\r\n",
          "Data de publicação": "29-04-2016"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "Editoria": "País",
      "Id": "574c58855db89f6a07313b69",
      "Notícias": [
        {
          "Foto": "5.jpg",
          "Título": "Homens e seus cães",
          "Texto": "Esse enim ad reprehenderit velit consectetur non eu deserunt. Commodo nostrud nulla dolore aliqua. Nisi excepteur ex dolore labore fugiat id voluptate velit incididunt aliqua adipisicing nisi ad incididunt. Aute et enim reprehenderit ipsum eiusmod enim aliquip dolor irure quis. Ad irure consequat mollit et tempor do sint et. Fugiat proident magna aliquip pariatur nisi eiusmod proident dolore mollit incididunt veniam quis. Irure eu quis in aliquip qui.\r\n",
          "Data de publicação": "24-04-2014"
        },
        {
          "Foto": "5.jpg",
          "Título": "Produtos falsificados",
          "Texto": "Consectetur exercitation labore nulla aliqua ullamco ad ut deserunt. Eu voluptate eiusmod id reprehenderit dolor nisi veniam dolor est deserunt mollit anim id irure. Adipisicing ex amet nostrud laboris adipisicing occaecat excepteur incididunt exercitation et dolore ad. Laborum dolore aute quis id reprehenderit dolore reprehenderit ut elit. Enim dolor est ullamco ad ipsum ad reprehenderit cupidatat. Velit reprehenderit irure elit incididunt proident aute adipisicing enim in.\r\n",
          "Data de publicação": "30-06-2014"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After changing a Noticias from Notícias to make the JSON work, here is what I THINK you want

```js
var data = {
  "Nome": "Notícias",
  "Editorias": [
    {
      "Editoria": "Esporte",
      "Id": "574c58853ecb94fd25aeb8a8",
      "Noticias": [
        {
          "Foto": "3.jpg",
          "Título": "Consumo de chocolate e depressão estão associados.",
          "Texto": "Sint dolor consequat occaecat non aliqua non adipisicing id. Lorem Lorem anim quis incididunt laboris consequat sunt id. Ad laborum magna ad non do dolor.\r\n",
          "Data de publicação": "06-01-2015"
        },
        {
          "Foto": "3.jpg",
          "Título": "Objetos recriados em madeira",
          "Texto": "Nisi deserunt irure deserunt est ut consequat consectetur enim aliqua fugiat ut minim. Minim amet velit aliquip aute id mollit incididunt veniam. Adipisicing elit duis dolore et. Proident occaecat qui ullamco incididunt ea pariatur aliquip veniam sit nisi officia aliquip.\r\n",
          "Data de publicação": "29-04-2016"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "Editoria": "País",
      "Id": "574c58855db89f6a07313b69",
      "Noticias": [
        {
          "Foto": "5.jpg",
          "Título": "Homens e seus cães",
          "Texto": "Esse enim ad reprehenderit velit consectetur non eu deserunt. Commodo nostrud nulla dolore aliqua. Nisi excepteur ex dolore labore fugiat id voluptate velit incididunt aliqua adipisicing nisi ad incididunt. Aute et enim reprehenderit ipsum eiusmod enim aliquip dolor irure quis. Ad irure consequat mollit et tempor do sint et. Fugiat proident magna aliquip pariatur nisi eiusmod proident dolore mollit incididunt veniam quis. Irure eu quis in aliquip qui.\r\n",
          "Data de publicação": "24-04-2014"
        },
        {
          "Foto": "5.jpg",
          "Título": "Produtos falsificados",
          "Texto": "Consectetur exercitation labore nulla aliqua ullamco ad ut deserunt. Eu voluptate eiusmod id reprehenderit dolor nisi veniam dolor est deserunt mollit anim id irure. Adipisicing ex amet nostrud laboris adipisicing occaecat excepteur incididunt exercitation et dolore ad. Laborum dolore aute quis id reprehenderit dolore reprehenderit ut elit. Enim dolor est ullamco ad ipsum ad reprehenderit cupidatat. Velit reprehenderit irure elit incididunt proident aute adipisicing enim in.\r\n",
          "Data de publicação": "30-06-2014"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}

var edt = data.Editorias, retorno = [], srcImg="";

for(var i = 0; i < edt.length; i++ ){
  var Noticias = edt[i].Noticias;
  for (var j=0;j<Noticias.length;j++) {
    console.log("editorial"+i,"Noticias"+j,edt[i].Noticias[j].Foto)
    retorno.push('<a href="#" class="trs"><img src="' + srcImg + edt[i].Noticias[j].Foto + '" class="img-resp" /></a>');
  }
}
$('.list-notices').html(retorno.join('\n'));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="list-notices"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

fix your script as below: you should not use `this` inside `$.getJSON` because it does refers `this` of `$.getJSON` not function variables

```
function jsonnoticias(){
    var srcImg = 'img/noticias/';
    var qtd;
    var retorno;

   $.getJSON('js/json/noticias.json', function(data, xhr){
        qtd = data.Foto.length; //put qtd instead of this.qtd
        retorno = ''; //remove put instead of this.retorno

        for(i = 0; i < qtd; i++ ){
            retorno +=  '<a href="#" class="trs"><img src="' + srcImg + data.Foto[i] + '" class="img-resp" /></a>';
        }
        $('.list-notices').html(retorno);
    });
}
```

Comment: There is no data.foto array either

Comment: It may exist on data

Comment: I removed the JQuery, I know that is wrong. I need a JQuery solution. I don't understand ver much about JSON.